# scipy's curve_fit is missing?

Tags: scipy, scipy-optimize

Win 10 x64 Python 3.7 Scipy version 1.3.2 - Anaconda

I have no idea why but `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` has vanished from my computer!

`scipy` & `scipy.optimize` still exist though.

Screen shot from my console...

[image]

What's going on here? Will it need a reinstall or am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
```